# md-nav-sref not working in md-nav-item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using `md-nav-bar` and can get it to work with `md-nav-href`. It switches routes when you click on a `md-nav-item`. However, it does not reflect a) URLs in the browser and b) programmatic route changes. So I tried using `md-nav-sref`, but with the effect that it does not even change the route anymore when clicking. Here is what I use:

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem">
    <md-nav-item name="overview" md-nav-sref="overview" ui-sref-active="active">Overview</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item name="howto" md-nav-sref="howto" ui-sref-active="active">How to</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
```

This is the route setup I use:

```
BlankApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/overview', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/overview.html'
        })
        .when('/howto', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/howto.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/overview'
        });
}]);
```

The documentation on `md-nav-bar` is very light, and there are no examples. Has anyone used `md-nav-bar` and can shed some light on how to use it?